# SCSS preprocessing problem using keyframe names

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to use Scss preprocessor with animations and I stumbled across some kind of error or bug.
I know how to fix it, but but I want to know what's wrong and what exactly is causing this error.

This is probably preprocessing error, in which you use similar keyframe names for animations and using SCSS variables in these animations. It can be solved by just changing name of keyframe animation.

If you compile example code, compiled CSS code in class `.game_not_hover` will have wrong name of keyframe for animation. To be specific, name will be `false`, which should be `not_hover_game`.

With just changing name of keyframe to something like `nhover_game` will solve this problem.

Also this can be solved just by changing variable `$animationLength` to a value `.4s`

---

Code example with error.

```css
$animationLength: .4s;
.game_not_hover {
    animation: not_hover_game $animationLength ease-in forwards;
}
.game_hover {
    animation: hover_game $animationLength ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes hover_game {
    0%{
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;    
    }
}
@keyframes not_hover_game {
    0%{
      opacity: 1; 
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
}
```

---

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BQP8.jpg - Image of error, made with https://beautifytools.com/scss-compiler.php

---

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBcIQ.jpg - Image of fix, made with https://beautifytools.com/scss-compiler.php

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely a bug in the flavor and version of the Sass compiler that beautifytools.com is using. Your code is fine and should produce `not_hover_game` in both places as expected.

However, the compiler you used seems to have interpreted `not` as the Sass [boolean negation operator](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/operators/boolean) and `_hover_game` as its argument. Since anything other than `false` and `null` is truthy in Sass, `_hover_game` is truthy and so `not _hover_game` (note the space) is `false`. That said, underscores are word characters in CSS and SCSS, so it is wrong for the compiler to treat `not` as a separate token.

A simple fix that works on the beautifytools.com compiler is just to quote `"not_hover_game"` when referenced in the `animation` property. That's valid (S)CSS anyway and forces the compiler to see one token.